# How to convert pandas dataframe to a sparse matrix using scipy's csr_matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to cast a DataFrame to sparse matrix using  `csr_matrix` from scipy library, but first I have to convert it to a SparseDataFrame. In previous versions of pandas I used `pd.SparseDataFrame(df).to_coo()` for such purposes, but since `pandas 1.0.0` this method is deprecated. Does anyone know how to perform such conversion using latest pandas api. I used this migration [guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating) and tried various combination but still unable to achieve desired result.
Following the guide, when I do the following

```
csr_matrix(pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(df).to_coo())
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tocsc'
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this? Also I do find other posts, but couldn't helped me in my case [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240096/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587702/convert-sparse-matrix-csc-matrix-to-pandas-dataframe) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578301/how-to-convert-panda-df-to-sparse-df)

Comment: Unless it's obvious what's producing the error, always include the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC and using the third link you shared, you can convert your `df` data to sparse data using `pd.SparseDtype`, like this

```
df_sparsed = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype("float", np.nan)
```

You can read more about `pd.SparseDtype` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.SparseDtype.html?highlight=sparsedtype#pandas.SparseDtype) to choose right parameters for your data and then use it in your above command like this:

```
csr_matrix(df_sparsed.sparse.to_coo()) # Note you need .sparse accessor to access .to_coo()
```

Simple one liner will be

```
csr_matrix(df.astype(pd.SparseDtype("float", np.nan)).sparse.to_coo())
```